# Making adjustments to multiple scripts similtaiounsly python

Tags: python

I am logging data from multiple assets from an exchange. I have parent script which is using multi threading to run all the scripts. The scripts are identical apart from the when the name of the asset is mentioned.

When I want to change something in the code I have to do it across all 10 scripts. Is there a program which allows me to change one master script, which when saved allows you to produce multiple scripts where certain fields are replaced by names in a list.

Ie

```
while INSERT == 5:
    do something 

Names = ['name1','name2',''name3']
```

Then produces 3 scripts where INSERT is replaced by each name in names

Comment: Surely what you should do is to just have 1 script that accepts input, and then figure out which assets to use based on that input. Then you can call that 10 times with multithreading.

Comment: Yeah, good point. I'll do this, thanks.